# How to find the indicator for stock amount in the code

Tags: magento-1.9, stock

I would like to know where you can find the indicator/code that says why a product is red/orange/green.

This is the code I found for what is still in stock. However, the stock is automatically tracked via a plug-in. And can not be adjusted in magento itself. Is there a way to indicate that when the stock is 0 it turns red, and the stock is 10 or less orange and 10 or more green?

Here I can change the text of the stock images, but how to change the indicator when it turns green/orange or red.

```
<div class="levertijd">
          <span class="title"><?php echo $this->__("Availability:")?></span>  
        <?php if($qtyStock > 0 and $_product->isAvailable()){?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/green.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('1 or more pieces in stock')?>"/>
         <?php }else if($qtyStock <= 0 and $_product->isAvailable()){?>
              <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/orange.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('1 in stock, please contact us')?>"/>
          <?php }else if(!$_product->isAvailable()){?>
                 <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/red.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('0 in stock, please contact us')?>"/>
          <?php } ?>  
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the trick! Due to stock with negative amount we changed it to this:

```
    <div class="levertijd">
          <span class="title"><?php echo $this->__("Availability:")?></span>  
        <?php if($qtyStock >= 5 and $_product->isAvailable()){?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/green.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('5 or more pieces in stock')?>"/>
         <?php }else if($qtyStock > 0 and $qtyStock < 5 and $_product->isAvailable()){?>
              <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/orange.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('less than 5 in stock')?>"/>
          <?php }else if($qtyStock <= 0 or !$_product->isAvailable()){?>
                 <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/red.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('0 in stock, please contact us')?>"/>
          <?php } ?>  
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<?php
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
$qtyStock =$stock->getQty();
?>


<div class="levertijd">
          <span class="title"><?php echo $this->__("Availability:")?></span>  
        <?php if($qtyStock > 10 and $_product->isAvailable()){?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/green.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('1 or more pieces in stock')?>"/>
         <?php }else if($qtyStock >= 0 and $_product->isAvailable()){?>
              <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/orange.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('1 in stock, please contact us')?>"/>
          <?php }else if(!$_product->isAvailable()){?>
                 <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/red.png')?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('0 in stock, please contact us')?>"/>
          <?php } ?>  
     </div>
```